# libopencv2.3-dev is not updated

Tags: ros, libopencv, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The libopencv2.3-dev version is not updated in the ubuntu repository. 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-1~natty is needed for ros-electric-vision-opencv but 2.3.0+svn5720+trunk-5~natty is in the repository. Where does this need to be reported?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10933/libopencv2.3-dev-is-not-updated/) by [Reemco](https://answers.ros.org/users/340/reemco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the report.  It should be resolved now if you run an 'apt-get update'

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bruno Normande](https://answers.ros.org/users/560/bruno-normande/) on 2011-10-23**:
Hummm... i'm getting the same error now, except that my installed version is 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-4~natty